# smartctl + how to found the XXX MBps throughput on disk

Tags: linux, hard-drive, redhat-enterprise-linux, throughput, smartctl

we want to know - How fast can a single storage volume read or write, in Megabytes per second

for example - 125MBps throughput.

so we used the `smartctl` command in order to capture the XXXMBps throughput. value

but we not found this info from smartctl

any other options?

```
 smartctl -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               SEAGATE
Product:              DL1800MM0159
Revision:             ST51
User Capacity:        1,800,360,124,416 bytes [1.80 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Physical block size:  4096 bytes
Lowest aligned LBA:   0
Formatted with type 2 protection
Logical block provisioning type unreported, LBPME=0, LBPRZ=0
Rotation Rate:        10000 rpm
Form Factor:          2.5 inches
Logical Unit id:      0x5000c500bc73d273
Serial number:        WBN12G02
Device type:          disk
Transport protocol:   SAS
Local Time is:        Tue Jul 19 10:49:47 2022 UTC
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Enabled
Temperature Warning:  Disabled or Not Supported

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Health Status: OK

Current Drive Temperature:     19 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        60 C

Manufactured in week 46 of year 2018
Specified cycle count over device lifetime:  10000
Accumulated start-stop cycles:  19
Specified load-unload count over device lifetime:  300000
Accumulated load-unload cycles:  1380
Elements in grown defect list: 0

Vendor (Seagate) cache information
  Blocks sent to initiator = 421312352
  Blocks received from initiator = 4275942608
  Blocks read from cache and sent to initiator = 4194898282
  Number of read and write commands whose size <= segment size = 316377477
  Number of read and write commands whose size > segment size = 3066756

Vendor (Seagate/Hitachi) factory information
  number of hours powered up = 29286.85
  number of minutes until next internal SMART test = 9

Error counter log:
           Errors Corrected by           Total   Correction     Gigabytes    Total
               ECC          rereads/    errors   algorithm      processed    uncorrected
           fast | delayed   rewrites  corrected  invocations   [10^9 bytes]  errors
read:   2663961716        5         0  2663961721          5      29253.063           0
write:         0        0        22        22         22     118463.418           0
verify:    64194        0         0     64194          0          0.000           0

Non-medium error count:     3382

No self-tests have been logged
```

Comment: I don’t see how _smartctl_ relates to this. It certainly displays some totals, but those are not even remotely precise enough. Just use a proper disk benchmark tool…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This...

```
$ lsblk -ap -e7  -o NAME,MOUNTPOINT,FSTYPE,LABEL,RO,RM,STATE,TYPE,SIZE,MODEL
NAME        MOUNTPOINT        FSTYPE LABEL RO RM STATE   TYPE   SIZE MODEL
...
```

... will give a nice table over available devices (excluding loop:s).

Pick one thing from the NAME column and use as $dev here...

```
sudo hdparm -Tt $dev
```

Oh, and you need this:
*$ sudo apt install hdparm*